# Adding kernel config option to Ubuntu Server installation .iso

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, iso

Is it possible to change the installation files in the `.iso` live image of Ubuntu Server, to add a certain kernel configuration option?

My goal is to enable `CONFIG_DMA_CMA`, so the kernel is compiled with CONFIG_DMA_CMA with every installation from this particular `.iso` image.

This, of course, depends on whether Ubuntu is actually building the kernel with every installation.

Comment: you could maybe take a look into https://linuxhint.com/customize_ubuntu_iso_create_spin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter because your system does not compile the Ubuntu kernel. It is built by Ubuntu and shipped in binary form, as virtually all distributions do. If you need a custom kernel you can follow [Ubuntu's directions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) for building a kernel and making deb packages from it.